# Basic Java Runtime program cannot find python

Tags: java, python, cmd, path, runtime

Hello working on a small program that just needs to run a python script I have. This python script will play a given .wav file, and draw a shape on the turtle screen. As such, I'm not looking for an output to be returned to java. Here is my java code:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python " + 
" D:/Coding Files/Python/MusicColors.py" +"  teenagers.wav");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": 
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I probably am making a very stupid mistake as I have limited knowledge in the subject of processes and such. I added python to my system path, so whenever I put "python" into command line, it returns with

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And makes it the python shell.

Here is the exact line I added to my environment path:
C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

If anyone can figure out where I went wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It may sounds stupid: have you tried restarting your computer? From my experience Path variable can be a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The $PATH variable you've set is not inherited in Java's execution context. Try passing the Python's bin path to `exec()`'s execution environment.

To do this, the code below first retrieve all the environment variables and create an array of ENV_KEY=ENV_VALUE pairs.

Then, the path to your Python's bin is appended to the PATH value.

Finally, we pass the array of all environment variables to `exec()` (via the second parameter).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            String[] commands = {"python D:/Coding Files/Python/MusicColors.py teenagers.wav"}; 

            // Get a list of all environment variables
            final Map<String, String> envMap = new HashMap<String, String>(System.getenv());

            // Append Python bin path to Path
            envMap.put("Path", envMap.get("Path") + ";C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32");

            // Convert to an array of ENV_KEY=ENV_VALUE format strings
            final String[] envs = new String[envMap.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : envMap.entrySet()) {
                envs[i] = e.getKey() + '=' + e.getValue();
                i++;
            }

            // Exec with the environment variables
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, envs); 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check where the python is installed? If on Windows, type `where python` in command line to see if you get C:/Users/Joe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe.

Comment: Yep, 'where python' returns C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe